# HQL query returing null value on use of like operator for search

Tags: hql

```
query = genericDAOImpl.getHibernateSession().createQuery("select t from ticket t where createdBy=:user and t.subject like concat("%", :summary, "%")
    .setParameter("user", userId)
    .setParameter("summary", inputBean.getSummary);
```

this is my query when I search for some values it returns the proper output but when I give null value for the search field  it returns empty list actually it should return all the values when the search field is empty

Answer (score 0):

You should just use a plain named placeholder for the predicate of the `LIKE` expression, and then bind the wildcard string from the Java side:

```
String sql = "select t from ticket t where createdBy = :user and t.subject like :summary";
query = genericDAOImpl.getHibernateSession().createQuery(sql);
query.setParameter("user", userId);
query.setParameter("summary", "%" + inputBean.getSummary + "%");
```